# Arrays in VB .NET

Tags: .net, vb.net, arrays

I'm new to .Net and haven't coded in Visual Basic in many years. I'm having trouble assigning values to an array and am getting the error, "Value of type MemberFocal.Member cannot be converted to System.Array" - MemberFocal.Member is part of a custom class and I am attempting to create an array of these objects. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here is the code:

```
    Public Function CreateMembersFromDataSet(ByVal memberDs As DataSet) As Array
        Dim returnval() As Array
        Dim memberTable As DataTableCollection
        Dim i As Integer = 0

        memberTable = memberDs.Tables

        For Each row As DataRow In memberTable
            ' error occurs on the following line
            returnval(i) = Me.CreateMemberWithId(row.Item("id").ToString)
            i += 1
        Next

        Return returnval
    End Function
```

Comment: `System.Array` is just a placeholder for a static array of `Member` or any other type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Dim returnval() As Array` creates an array of `Array` values.

You want `Dim returnval() As Member`.

Comment: One thing to note, Dim returnVal() As Member is the same as Dim returnVal As Member()

Comment: `Dim returnval(memberTable.Count - 2) As Member` check this for some insight in arrays declarations http://j.mp/smmUkV

Comment: @Gent But still that declaration is only for backwards compatibility with old VB6 and so discouraged (but yes, it works the same).

Comment: @PedroC88 Good to know, too me putting part of the type definition anywhere but the type seems backwards, but I guess there must be some reason for it? :D